# some problems with obtaining the value of functions within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I'm just starting out in Python, but I'm attempting to implement functions within dictionaries (kind of like function pointers in C), but I'm stuck on how to receive the returned value from the function without an error. Here's a snippit from my code:

```
def main():
    numberOfDice = 5
    dice = rollDice(numberOfDice) #rolls dice thrice, returns a list of 5 integers
    scoreBoard(dice)   #displays Yahtzee scoreboard
    value = choice(dice)  #value = the category choice[1-13]
    whichCategory(value) 

def whichCategory(category):
    board = {
        6: numberOfSixes, # I have 1-13 filled, but just for example
        12: yahtzee       # this is just to save space.
        }
    board[category]()

def numberOfSixes(theDice):
    count = theDice.count(6)
    points = count * 6

    return points

def yahtzee(theDice):
    yahtzee = 0
    ones, twos, threes, fours, fives, sixes = countDice(theDice)
    # countDice() determines the amount that each number is present in the 
    # list and then returns those six variables.
    if any(x==5 for x in(ones, twos, threes, fours, fives, sixes)):
           yahtzee = 50

    return yahtzee
```

After rolling three times and I finalize my dice (the list of integers), I select my value from choice that goes with whichCategory(), and then it does the correct calculations, spits out the correct return value from those functions, but then I'll get an error like this(for inputting in two sixes(12 pts)):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python\Lib\idlelib\Yahtzee.py", line 407, in <module>
main()   # My call to main()
File "C:\python\Lib\idlelib\Yahtzee.py", line 18, in main
whichCategory(value)
File "C:\python\Lib\idlelib\Yahtzee.py", line 90, in whichCategory
board[category]()
TypeError: yahtzee() missing 1 required positional argument: 'theDice
```

It's funny because it says the error is with yahtzee(), not the sixes, and I believe it's because it's somehow getting 12 as an answer and it's calling the 12th keyword in the dictionary. or I'll get an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python\Lib\idlelib\Yahtzee.py", line 407, in <module>
main()   # My call to main()
File "C:\python\Lib\idlelib\Yahtzee.py", line 18, in main
whichCategory(value)
File "C:\python\Lib\idlelib\Yahtzee.py", line 90, in whichCategory
board[category]()
KeyError: 50
```

Please, I've looked for answers, but have yet to find any. If possible, I'd like to return the values from the functions within the dictionary back to main(). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are writing your code with `tabs` aren't you ...

Comment: Yeah, I believe I just followed the instructions, but if there's a better way to post code, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but I think the problem is that at the line `board[category]()`, you call one of your functions, but not with the value it needs.  Try making these changes

```
def main():
    numberOfDice = 5
    dice = rollDice(numberOfDice) #rolls dice thrice, returns a list of 5 integers
    scoreBoard(dice)   #displays Yahtzee scoreboard
    value = choice(dice)  #value = the category choice[1-13]
    whichCategory(value, dice) # pass dice

def whichCategory(category, dice):  # receive dice
    board = {
        6: numberOfSixes, # I have 1-13 filled, but just for example
        12: yahtzee       # this is just to save space.
        }
    board[category](dice)   # call with dice
```

Comment: I tested this code multiple times, and it did make things somewhat smoother when the value of the individual function was 13 points or below, but even then it was hit or miss when actually returning the value, which boggles me. Why would it change, unless the position of the dice in the list matter? I don't have any idea.

Comment: However, when the score is above 13 points, I receive the same Key error as before.

Comment: UPDATE: I was mistaken, your suggestion works perfectly! I had written some alternative code that was less efficient than whichCategory(), and I had kept it within my code when testing whichCategory()...rookie mistake. Sorry for the misleading feedback, but thank you yet again for your suggestion!